# Why does this MySQL insert fail with foreign key constraint error?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, foreign-keys

I'm at a loss here. I can't figure out why this insert fails:

```
insert into lokacijaSubjekta (lokacijaSubjektaID, subjektID, lokacijaID) values (NULL, '1', '1');
```

It fails with:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`nano`.`lokacijaSubjekta`, CONSTRAINT `fk_lokacijaSubjekta_subjekt1` FOREIGN KEY (`subjektID`) REFERENCES `subjekt` (`subjektID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Here's how the keys are set up:

```
show index from lokacijaSubjekta;
+------------------+------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name                          | Seq_in_index | Column_name        | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+------------------+------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| lokacijaSubjekta |          0 | PRIMARY                           |            1 | lokacijaSubjektaID | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| lokacijaSubjekta |          1 | fk_lokacijaSubjekta_lokacija1_idx |            1 | lokacijaID         | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| lokacijaSubjekta |          1 | fk_lokacijaSubjekta_subjekt1      |            1 | subjektID          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+------------------+------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

show index from subjekt;
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| subjekt |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | subjektID   | A         |       35603 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

And this is the data in the tables:

```
select * from subjekt where subjektID=1;
+-----------+---------------+
| subjektID | subjektPravni |
+-----------+---------------+
|         1 |             1 |
+-----------+---------------+

select * from lokacija where lokacijaID = 1;
+------------+------------------+------------------+
| lokacijaID | geografskaSirina | geografskaDuzina |
+------------+------------------+------------------+
|          1 |             NULL |             NULL |
+------------+------------------+------------------+

select * from lokacijaSubjekta;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

At first I thought it was because I had primary key constraint in `lokacijaSubjekta` set to `(subjektID, lokacijaID)`, and also a foreign key from `subjektID` referencing `subjekt.subjektID`, so I removed that primary key and added an extra `auto_increment` column `lokacijaSubjektaID` to use as primary key instead, but nothing changed.

EDIT: Here are table descriptions, as requested:

```
describe subjekt;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| subjektID     | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| subjektPravni | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

describe lokacija;
+------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| lokacijaID       | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| geografskaSirina | decimal(18,12) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| geografskaDuzina | decimal(18,12) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

describe lokacijaSubjekta;
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| lokacijaSubjektaID | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subjektID          | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| lokacijaID         | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

There are no triggers.

```
show triggers;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

EDIT 2: I was able to resolve this by dropping the table `subjekt` and re-creating it along with all the foreign keys, then refilling data. While doing this, I noticed some other tables that referenced `subjekt` had mismathced signedness on the referenced column, then more tables referencing those tables, and this basically cascaded over most of the tables in the database. When I fixed all the signedness mismatches and restored foreign key constraints, I could insert data to `lokacijaSubjekta` without further problems.

Comment: It seems that you are assigning `NULL` to a `PRIMARY KEY` in `lokacijaSubjekta`.

Comment: what are the data types of all the columns? Are there any triggers?

Comment: @PM77-1 I can do that, since that column is `auto_increment` and MySQL will assign the key automatically.

Comment: What is different between http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a16b/1 and what you have? What version of MySQL is it?

Answer (score 1):

The error is essentially saying that the value you are supplying for the foreign key column (the second column in your INSERT) **`'1'`** is **not found** in the `subjectID` column of the `subjekt` table.

From everything you've shown, it appears that the value is there. MySQL normally interprets a string literal like that in a numeric context, and it should evaluate to integer value `1`. It's possible there's some setting in sql_mode that's making MySQL more "strict" than it is by default. Check your setting of sql_mode

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
```

You could try adding a 0 to the string literal,

```
SELECT '1'+0  and verify it returns integer value of 1.
```

You could also try that in the INSERT statement, or try removing the single quotes, but I don't think that will make a difference (apart from some strange setting of sql_mode).

You said you already verified there aren't any triggers interfering with the INSERT.

Some other possibilities to consider:

Was the row with subjekID=1 inserted into the `subjekt` by another session, as part of a transaction, and a `COMMIT` has not yet been issued?  (If you're using InnoDB, do a `SHOW INNODB STATUS` command to get more information about the last foreign key error.)

Was a previous incarnation of the `subjekt` table renamed, moved to a different database, and a new `subjekt` table created? An existing foreign key references "stays" with the table it was referencing, it may be referencing the "old" table in the other schema.  You could check the `information_schema.constraints` table, check the schema of the table, and of the referenced table.

Since subjektID is the PRIMARY KEY, we wouldn't expect that InnoDB index corruption would be an issue.

After checking those things, I'm stumped.

Is it possible that invalid data already exists, data was inserted when `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` was disabled... and in this session `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` is enabled, and it's this insert statement that's causing InnoDB to "check" some *other* rows in the table, and not just the one being inserted?

What storage engine? What version of MySQL?

It's a puzzle.

Comment: There _was_ another incarnation of `subjekt`, but I dropped it and replaced it with a new `subjekt`. It definitely didn't end up in another database, because this is the only one I'm using, and for now I'm the only one using it. I hope. In any case, your answer is very informative.

Comment: @Nikola Novak: I omitted from my answer, how to check if there are any existing rows in the child table that have "invalid" foreign key values, anti-join pattern: `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM lokacijaSubjekta c LEFT JOIN subjekt p ON p.subjektid = c.subjektid WHERE p.subjecktid IS NULL;` or you could use a `NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)` to see if count is zero. (If it's >0, there's non-null foreign key values that aren't valid.) (I'm not sure if `foreign_key_checks` should be disabled when the query runs; if the optimizer might "know" the count is zero without actually performing the operation.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **[Default or 0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)** instead of **null** and if you correct the references sometime you should disconnect your IDE and reconnect it.

Try:

```
insert into lokacijaSubjekta (lokacijaSubjektaID, subjektID, lokacijaID) values (Default, '1', '1');
```

Comment: As I see you don't have foreign key constraint error after your fix,Can I know what is the error msg now?

Comment: I don't see how the value supplied in the INSERT for the primary key would have any influence on the foreign key constraint violation. (But using `Default` in place of `NULL` keyword is new to me.) Using `0` in place of `NULL` should give same result *unless* `sql_mode` includes `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`. Omitting the AUTO_INCREMENT primary key column from the INSERT would also give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because you have put string delimiters around your integer values, transforming them into char values:

```
... values (NULL, '1', '1');
```

instead of

```
... values (NULL, 1, 1);
```

The Ascii value of the char '1' is inserted instead of the value 1.

Also, if lokacijaSubjektaID is an autoincrement value, you should try to insert a Null value into it.  You need to remove this column entirely from your insert statement.